# JavaFX - Odd behavior from GridPane with DatePicker

Tags: java, layout, javafx, datepicker, gridpane

GridPane does not seem to size properly when containing DatePickers.  Anyone have an idea what's going on or a potential work around?  I have tried a number of other nodes (CheckBox, ChoiceBox, etc.) and DatePicker seems to be the only one that causes this behavior.  Thoughts?

EDIT: ColorPicker and ComboBox both seem to be fine despite also extending ComboBoxBase as DatePicker does.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  HBox goodBox = new HBox();
  goodBox.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green");
  goodBox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
  GridPane goodGrid = new GridPane();
  goodGrid.setHgap(5);
  goodGrid.setVgap(5);
  goodGrid.addColumn(0, new Label("Good 1:"), new Label("Good 2:"));
  goodGrid.addColumn(1, new TextField(), new TextField());
  goodBox.getChildren().add(goodGrid);

  HBox badBox = new HBox();
  badBox.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red");
  badBox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
  GridPane badGrid = new GridPane();
  badGrid.setHgap(5);
  badGrid.setVgap(5);
  badGrid.addColumn(0, new Label("Bad 2:"), new Label("Bad 2:"));
  badGrid.addColumn(1, new DatePicker(), new DatePicker());
  badBox.getChildren().add(badGrid);

  VBox root = new VBox(5);
  root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
  root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
  root.getChildren().addAll(goodBox, badBox);

  Scene scene = new Scene(root);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  launch(args);
}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following when setting the Scene and showing the Stage seems to work:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
root.applyCss();
root.layout();
primaryStage.show();
```

I would love some insight as to why this is necessary.